# "again called you yesterday" or "called you again yesterday"

Tags: sentence-construction

I tried to call a friend yesterday and wanted to let her know that I have tried calling her. Do I write

> **A**: I **again** called you yesterday

or

> **B**: I called you **again** yesterday

Comment: Option B sounds much more natural.

Comment: I've seen both usages, but (to me) the second 'feels' more natural.

Comment: Related: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/121180/word-order-of-adverbs; https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/60165/adverbial-adjectivial-phrase-placement

Comment: ...but _"Yesterday I called you again"_ might be most idiomatic.

Comment: Should there be a comma after yesterday ?

Answer (score 1):

> A: I **again** called you *yesterday*

is correct, but unnatural.

---

> B: I called you **again** *yesterday*

is more natural.

---

You can also use:

> I called you *yesterday* **again**

or

> *Yesterday* I called you **again**

Answer (score -2):

Both options have different **subjects**.

> I again **called you yesterday**.
>
> I **called you** again yesterday.

In this case, the subject is **you calling her**. 'Again' and 'yesterday' contribute to the subject, and should not be part of it.

Option B is the best.

Comment: The subject of the first sentence is **"I"**. The subject of the second is also **"I"**. The phrase _"you calling her"_ does not appear in either sentence, and cannot be the subject.

Comment: Someone is trying to let their friend know that they called them and that they didn't pick up. That's the subject. That's what they're trying to convey.

Comment: That is the topic, not the subject in strict sentence construction.

Comment: [Subject, theme, topic are often interchangeable to express the material being considered in a speech or written composition.](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/subject)

Comment: Don't you think it is foolish to attempt to instruct us in the use of our own language? As you would understand had you read our Tour and Help pages, this site is concerned with assisting persons (such as you yourself) whose native language is not English, in learning the grammar and usage of the English language. In that context of grammar, the word _subject_ has a specific meaning. In your answer, you misuse the word _subject_ in a way that is certain to confuse many learners.

Comment: Who's _our_? I'm a native speaker. I don't need assistance from you to speak the language I've been speaking all my life. Not only that, but you're completely ignoring the fact that words have multiple meanings. I did not explicitly state that I was eluding to that particular meaning of the word, and any suggestion that I did so is false. If learners are confused, they can ask for help and do not need someone to speak up for them. Your continual criticism is becoming incendiary, and is more personally motivated than helpful. I referenced a dictionary - does _that_ need assistance?

Comment: It is precisely those multiple meanings, and the confusion they may elicit in new students of English, that your answer ignores. If you mean to say _Topic_ (see user3169), then say that. _Subject_ is something else in the context of grammar, which point my comment was intended to make. ("Incendiary"? The use of that adjective in this context hardly supports the argument that you're a native speaker!  Better have another go at the thesaurus. And what is it that you are "eluding"? I'd look that verb up too, if I were you, with or without assistance. Hint: while you're at it, look up _"allude"_.)

Comment: I'm ignoring multiple meanings? What do you think I've been trying to advocate for the past _16 hours_ now? Incendiary [is a proper adjective](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/incendiary), and "elude" was my mistake. You're still making incorrect and ignorant assumptions that I don't speak the language because I worded something in a way you didn't understand. English, like all languages, is spoken by many people, who all word things differently. Snobbery and totalitarianism have no place, in this forum or anywhere, and they discourage people from learning English at all.